# Finding the occurance of seeing word A followed by everything but B using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a string, and I want to find the number of all ocuurances of word A followed by any word but word B using preg_match or preg_match_all in PHP.

For example, suppose that A = 'Hello' and B='Bye', and our string is Str = 'Hello world, Hello Bye, Hello Andy'. Then we should be able to find "Hello world" and "Hello Andy" using preg_match. Any idea how we can do this? Thanks!

Comment: There are moments when common sense beat regular expressions and this is one of them. Split the text in words and loop over them counting all matches of 'Hello' that aren't followed by 'Bye'. This is not a task for regular expressions even if it's easily achievable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'Hello world, Hello Bye, Hello Andy, Hello';
// initialize counters first
$count_hellos = $count_hello_byes = $count_hello_no_byes = 0;
// look for Hello - Bye
if(preg_match_all('~\\bHello\\b~si', $text, $matches)){
    $count_hellos = count($matches[0]);
    unset($matches);
}
// look for Hello + Bye
if(preg_match_all('~Hello\\W+Bye~si', $text, $matches)){
    $count_hello_byes = count($matches[0]);
    unset($matches);
}
// do the math
$count_hello_no_byes = $count_hellos - $count_hello_byes;
var_dump($count_hello_no_byes); // what you are looking for
```

^ **easily achievable like this**!

[**LEARN MORE HERE**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand) about *RegEx Shorthand character classes*.

Comment: BTW, what does \\b~si mean?

Comment: @BlueSky `\b` means word border and includes both `^`(begin), `$`(end). `\W` means not a word character but does not include `^` and `$`.

Comment: @BlueSky `~...~` is what I use instead of `/.../` what everyone else uses. Regexps can be wrapped in other characters, not only `/`. And `si` are flags means `single line`, `case insensitive`.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this

```
<?
$text = 'Hello world, Hello Bye, Hello Andy';
$a = 'Hello';
$b = 'Bye';
$counter = 0;
$words = explode(' ',$text);
foreach($words as $i => $word){
    $word = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $word));
    if($word==strtolower($a) && isset($words[$i+1]) && strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $words[$i+1]))!=strtolower($b)){
        $counter++;
    }
}
echo $counter;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
$haystack = 'Hello world, Hello Bye, Hello Andy';
$pattern = '/\bHello\W+(?!Bye)(\w+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $haystack, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => world
    [1] => Andy
)
*/
```

if the A and B values are dynamic, make sure to use `preg_quote()` to escape them before interpolating them into the pattern string.